# How can I edit the content of a file in windows, from Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I was probe many options, but nothing function.

For example, I am try to modify the file "test.yaml", changing the text "image:v3" for "image:v4".

I was probe from powershell console directly and is OK, but from Jenkins I receive error: "foreach-object is not recognize as command"

```
pipeline {
  agent any  
       stages {           
           stage('MODIFY TEXT') {
        
          steps {
              script  {
bat 'powershell.exe (get-content D:\\Code\\yamls\\test.yaml) | foreach-object {$_ -replace "image:v3", "image:v4"} | set-content D:\\Code\\yamls\\test.yaml'
                    }
                }
           }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `powershell` (5.x) or `pwsh` (7.x) step:

```
pipeline {
    agent any  
    stages {           
        stage('MODIFY TEXT') {       
            steps {
                powershell '''
                    $lines = get-content D:\\Code\\yamls\\test.yaml 
                    $lines | foreach-object {$_ -replace "image:v3", "image:v4"} | set-content D:\\Code\\yamls\\test.yaml
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello  zett42 !! Thank yoy very much !!! I am probing your code, and the old error disapear. !! Now show another error said:  "powershell.exe: set-content: Process can not access to file ..... because another process is using  " I verified, and closed the file and continue the same error.

Comment: @YasserMoreno You have the same input and output file path, so you can't read and write at the same time. So first read file completely into variable, then process variable and save file. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes now!!! Spectacular! It worked ! Thank you very much @zett42 !!!!

Comment: Hello @zett42! The text change whitout problem! Thank you very much!! But, when I need made a change , using a parameter defined at the pipeline, does not make the change! Any idea about this! Thank you very much!

Comment: @YasserMoreno Do not insert Groovy variable directly in PS code. It is very insecure because it can enable code injection. You can use environment variable instead: `-replace "image:v3", $env:TAG`

Comment: @YasserMoreno Regarding code injection: https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/automating-with-jenkinsfile/string-interpolation#_injection_via_interpolation

Comment: Waoo @zett42!!! You are a genius !!! Thank you very much! It function!